# Como puedo agregar una finalización de función de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy implementando una subida de archivos desde un script para mi drive, funciona a la perfección solo que no pasa de aquí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera, es que avisara que la imagen se subió correctamente.

Tengo este código:

```
<form id="form">
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">&nbsp;<input name="filename" id="filename" placeholder="Nombre y fecha" type="text">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Subir Archivo" onclick="this.value='subiendo..';
                        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                        .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                        return false;">
    </form>
    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const file = form.file.files[0];
            const fr = new FileReader();
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            fr.onload = f => {
    
                const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwe9gbNnTHn5RJnWHOz0-tgb0bp_GLEsiXZ0l_4i5yWT5sUibNO1chyizz50bhBE9mlWQ/exec"; // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
     
                const qs = new URLSearchParams({
                    filename: form.filename.value || file.name,
                    mimeType: file.type
                });
                fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])
                    })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(e => console.log()) // return. <--- You can retrieve the returned value here.
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        });
    </script>
```

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, estás usando una mala práctica, estás usando mucho código en el atributo `onclick` y esto hace tu código, en parte, "feo".

Además, he de decir que los atributos de eventos en HTML (`on*`, ejemeplo: `onclick`) **NO** deberían ponerse, al parecer solo has copiado y pegado un código que no comprendes.

Primero, debemos añadir un `eventListener` a tu botón, para ello vamos obtenerlo por su atributo `id`, mediante el método `document.getElementById` y sobreescribir el código que pusiste en el `onclcik` dentro del manejador del evento

En el resto del código, con `fetch` haces una petición a un servidor externo, es decir, envías información a un servidor, el cual la procesa y te devuelve una respuesta, en el segundo `then` del `fetch` sabremos que la petición fue exitosa, ahí cambiaremos el `value` de tu botón

```html
<form id="form">
   <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">&nbsp;<input name="filename" id="filename" placeholder="Nombre y fecha" type="text">
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Subir Archivo">
</form>
<script>
   const form = document.getElementById('form');
   const btn = document.getElementByID('submit');
 
   form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
       e.preventDefault();

      btn.value='subiendo..';
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
      .uploadFiles(btn.parentNode);

       const file = form.file.files[0];
       const fr = new FileReader();
       fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
       fr.onload = f => {
   
           const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwe9gbNnTHn5RJnWHOz0-tgb0bp_GLEsiXZ0l_4i5yWT5sUibNO1chyizz50bhBE9mlWQ/exec"; // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
   
           const qs = new URLSearchParams({
               filename: form.filename.value || file.name,
               mimeType: file.type
           });
           fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {
                   method: "POST",
                   body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])
               })
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then(e => {
                   // Aquí sabremos la respuesta, "e" es la respuesta
                   // Modificamos el valor del botón para indicar que todo ha ido bien
                   btn.value = "subida completa";
                   console.log("Respuesta:", e);
               })
               .catch(err => {
                   // Algo ha ido mal
                   // Indicar que ha ido mal
                   alert("Algo ha ido mal, comprueba la consola para visualizar el error");
                   console.log(err)
               });
       }
   });
</script>
```